# Python N_gram frequency count

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram

I have a pandas data frame and I want to do 2-gram frequency based on one text column.

```
text_column
This is a book
This is a book that is read
This is a book but he doesn't think this is a book
```

The final result would like is a frequency count of 2 gram **but** the frequency is counting whether a 2 gram is in each document, not a 2-gram count.

So the partial result would be

```
2 gram         Count
This is          3
a book           3
```

"This is" and "a book" appeared in the all 3 texts although there are 2 of each of the 3rd text, since I'm only interested how many documents did such 2 gram appeared, the counting is 3 so not 4.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Pythonic answer (wrote it general so can be applied to a file/dataframe/whatever):

```
c=collections.Counter()
for i in fh:
  x = i.rstrip().split(" ")
  c.update(set(zip(x[:-1],x[1:])))
```

Now `c` holds the frequency of every 2-gram.

**Explanation:**

1. Every line is `split` by whitespace into a list.
2. Then `zip()` to return an iterator over tuples of length 2 (the 2 grams).
3. The iterator is fed into a `set()` in order to remove redundancies.
4. Then the set is fed into a `collections.Counter()` object, which keeps track of how many times each tuple appeared. You need to `import collections` to use this.
5. It is easy now to list the contents of the Counter or convert it to any other format you like (e.g. dataframe).

Yes, Python is awesome.

Comment: I like your solution a lot better than mine! +1

Comment: Thanks for your solution! QQ: How to make this into trigram?

Comment: @Abbey I think you just substitute the last line to be: `c.update(set(zip(x[:-2],x[1:-1],x[2:])))`

Answer (score 0):

This is very c-style, but works. Idea is to keep track of the "current" bigrams per document, making sure that they're added only once per doc (`cur_bigrams = set()`), and after each document, increment a global freq counter (`bigram_freq`) if it was in the current document. Then build a new dataframe out of the info in `bigram_freq`, the global counter across documents.

```
bigram_freq = {}
for doc in df["text_column"]:
    cur_bigrams = set()
    words = doc.split(" ")
    bigrams = zip(words, words[1:])
    for bigram in bigrams:
        if bigram not in cur_bigrams: # Add bigram, but only once/doc
            cur_bigrams.add(bigram)
    for bigram in cur_bigrams:
        if bigram in bigram_freq:
            bigram_freq[bigram] += 1
        else:
            bigram_freq[bigram] = 1

result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["2_gram", "count"])
row_list = []
for bigram, freq in bigram_freq.items():
    row_list.append([bigram[0] + " " + bigram[1], freq])
for i in range(len(row_list)):
    result_df.loc[i] = row_list[i]

print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
           2_gram count
0          a book     3
1            is a     3
2         This is     3
3         is read     1
4         that is     1
5       book that     1
6      he doesn't     1
7         this is     1
8        book but     1
9          but he     1
10     think this     1
11  doesn't think     1
```

You can probably trim that code down a good bit using a more functional style and/or list comprehensions. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.